# Sorting lists by multiple criteria and appending

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-3.x

I am trying to figure out a way to sort multiple lists simultaneously then split up by unique value and sort again then flatten and output.

```
room_number = [100,200,300,100,400,300]
door_angle =  [ 20, 65, 118, 10, 13,50]
door =        [dr1,dr2,dr3,dr4,dr5,dr6]
```

I want to sort lists by the room number first and split those up into sublists containing the repeating room_number values as follows:

```
room_number = [[100,100],[200],[300,300],[400]]
door_angle = [[20,10],[65],[118,50],[13]]
door = [[dr1,dr4],[dr2],[dr3,dr6],[dr5]]
```

then i want to further sort the sublists by the door_angle:

```
room_number = [[100,100],[200],[300,300],[400]]
door_angle = [[10,20],[65],[50,118],[13]]
door = [[dr4,dr1],[dr2],[dr6,dr3],[dr5]]
```

how would i approach this problem?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A = [100, 200, 300, 100, 400, 300]
B = [20, 65, 118, 10, 13, 50]
C = ['dr1', 'dr2', 'dr3', 'dr4', 'dr5', 'dr6']

print(list(map(list, map(list, A))))
# [[100, 100], [200], [300, 300], [400]]
print(list(map(list, map(list, B))))
# [[10, 20], [65], [50, 118], [13]]
print(list(map(list, map(list, C))))
# [['dr4', 'dr1'], ['dr2'], ['dr6', 'dr3'], ['dr5']]
```

First, we `zip` all the values together and sort them and then group the values based on the first values. Then its just a matter of unzipping and getting the data back in the expected shape.

Comment: yes this is all new to me. I am a newbie with Python. Thank you for help. Also, when I am trying to run it i am getting an error:<map object at 0x0000000003433860>
<map object at 0x00000000034334E0>
<map object at 0x0000000003433860>

Comment: @user3263488 Looks like you are using Python 3.x, please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.

```
from itertools import groupby

A = [100,200,300,100,400,300]
B = [ 20, 65, 118, 10, 13,50]
C = ['dr1', 'dr2', 'dr3', 'dr4', 'dr5', 'dr6']

grps = sorted(zip(A, B, C), key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))
A, B, C = [], [] ,[]
for i, grp in groupby(grps, lambda x: x[0]):
    subA, subB, subC = [], [] ,[]
    for j in grp:
        subA.append(j[0])
        subB.append(j[1])
        subC.append(j[2])
    A.append(subA)
    B.append(subB)
    C.append(subC)
```

output:

```
>>> A
[[100, 100], [200], [300, 300], [400]]

>>> B
[[10, 20], [65], [50, 118], [13]]

>>> C
[['dr4', 'dr1'], ['dr2'], ['dr6', 'dr3'], ['dr5']]
```